# Select a specific text in jquery

Tags: jquery, select, text, get

How can I select the text between 2 guidelines which are 2 words?

Example:

> Lorem ipsum **dolor** sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer congue venenatis consectetur. Suspendisse in pretium elit, id euismod odio. Quisque sem lorem, laoreet et feugiat eget, elementum eu felis. Nunc quis nisi tellus. Vivamus pulvinar diam erat. Vestibulum rutrum pharetra eros, nec scelerisque nibh pellentesque vitae. Aliquam vitae justo elit. Sed dapibus interdum mollis. Nunc a volutpat quam. **Curabitur** malesuada tempor cursus.

I need to get as output all text from **dolor** to **Curabitur** by using these 2 words as  markers.

Comment: Is this text in a textarea, or just in an element on the page? Select usually implies a textarea, but I wonder if you just mean you want to get the text between those words into a variable.

Comment: Post the code you've tried.

Comment: @Jamiec It is in a textarea for now, dont think to change it to a div, but i may need this later.

Comment: @j08691 i haven't tried any code because i'm pretty new to jquery.

Comment: @Jamiec i need to get this text in a variable to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var p = $('p'),
    text = p.text();

console.log(
    text.substr(
        text.indexOf('dolor'),
        text.indexOf('Curabitur') -
            text.indexOf('dolor') +
            'Curabitur'.length
    )
);
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/reLvn8tk/1/)</kbd>

## Quick explanation

First we get the index of the word `dolor`. That's the starting point.

After that, we get the index of the word `Curabitur`. Then we remove the index of the word `dolor` since we are indexing on the original text and not the cutted down by the word `dolor`.

Finally, if we want to get the word `Curabitur` aswell, just add the length of the word to the index.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the script and especially for the explanation, 1 step closer to become a jquery god :)

Comment: This is not particularly jQuery, the `substr` and `indexOf` are native JavaScript functions. The only jQuery used here is the method to get the DOM element. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = document.getElementById('textareaID').value;
var snippet = text.substring(text.indexOf('dolor'), text.indexOf('Curabitur'));
```

Answer (score 1):

javascript:

```js
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer congue venenatis consectetur. Suspendisse in pretium elit, id euismod odio. Quisque sem lorem, laoreet et feugiat eget, elementum eu felis. Nunc quis nisi tellus. Vivamus pulvinar diam erat. Vestibulum rutrum pharetra eros, nec scelerisque nibh pellentesque vitae. Aliquam vitae justo elit. Sed dapibus interdum mollis. Nunc a volutpat quam. Curabitur malesuada tempor cursus.';

//or: var text = $(element).text();
var snippet = text.substring(text.indexOf('dolor'), 
                             text.indexOf('Curabitur') + 'Curabitur'.length);
alert(snippet)
```